# Jena Riot Exception while updating ontology in Jena TDB dataset

Tags: jena

In my application , I am trying to update the content of an ontology already present in TDB. Before getting stored in TDB, I convert the ontology in RDF/XML format. While loading ontology data in empty model using same model.read method does not create issue but while updating it gives this Error. Can someone help me with solution ? 
Input Arguments : modelName ->namedModel saved in TDB 
                  inputString ->ontology data converted to String 
My code is as below :

```
public void updateModel(String modelName, String inputString) {
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
    try {
        Model model = dataset.getNamedModel(modelName);
        model.removeAll();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(inputString);
        model.read(reader,null,"RDF/XML-ABBREV");
        dataset.commit();
        logger.info("dataset committed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Exception in reading : " + e);
    } finally {
        dataset.end();
    }

}
```

It throws the following error : org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 1 ] Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: "Content is not allowed in prolog. " is an error from XML parsing.   inputString is not a legal RDF/XML document. (and the "read" should be "RDF/XML", not "-ABBREV", which is for output).

Comment: but while importing an ontology I am using the same format for read. that is RDF/XML-ABBREV. Also I check my XML data has no additional input before declaration. What possible errors could be there in XML ? Can you elaborate more how can i rectify this error ? Thanks

Comment: The "read" should be "RDF/XML", not "RDF/XML-ABBREV". The RDF/XML reader can read all legal forms.

Comment: The error is at the start of the input. Check "inputStream" (which is not a filename - it is the content to process as a stream of characters).

Comment: I am not passing file anywhere. I did not get you .

Comment: What is the value of "inputString"?

Comment: It's  a string format for JSON-LD

Comment: If it is not RDF/XML content, the RDF/XML reader can't parse it. That's what the model.read is doing - parsing the given string via the StringReader.